# Testing serverless with Mocha plugin

Tags: testing, mocha.js, serverless-framework

I have been using serverless for a while now, however this is the first time I'm trying to use mocha for writing tests. When I'm trying to run the following `sls create test --function insiders/create.create` I get the following error `Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined`. This is how my serverless.yml looks like for the handler I have created

```
createInsider:
    handler: insiders/create.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: insiders
          method: post
          cors: true
```

This is how the plugin Mocha is defined

```
plugins:
  - serverless-mocha-plugin
```

The code is deployed and it works fine. The namespacing is as `insiders/create.js` is where I have defined my function.

```
module.exports.create = () => {}
```

I have also tried the following ways

```
sls create test --function insiders/create

sls create test --function create
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it answers your question, but since majority of the business logic for serverless code is just regular javascript, you can use mocha directly for unit testing.

```
npm install --save-dev mocha
```

In package.json

```
  "test": "mocha test/**/*test.js",
```

Create a test folder and corresponding test files under it 
Ex: for src/insiders/create.js create test/insiders/create.test.js

For every handler test the outputs for different inputs

For callback style

```
describe('create', () => {
  it('should execute', (done) => {
    const event = {};
    const context = {};
    const callback = (_, response) => {
        //assert required things
        done();
    };
    const handler = require('../../src/insiders/create.js');
    handler(event, context, callback)
  });
});
```

For async await style

```
describe('create', () => {
  it('should execute', async () => {
    const event = {};
    const handler = require('../../src/insiders/create.js');
    const result = await handler(event);
    //assert the result
  });
});
```

We use this style and it works very well for us.

Edit: Fix the mocha glob pattern to search recursively for all test files.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have written unit tests using Mocha before, but when I'm using it specially with Serverless and the plugin it provides to build the function, is when I'm getting the error.